# Password Confirmation in Node.js & React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am following this awesome [tutorial](https://vladimirponomarev.com/blog/authentication-in-react-apps-creating-components) in learning how to do a signup/login feature in Node.js and React.js. I am trying to implement a confirmation password feature where a user needs to enter their password a second time when signing up. I already created a field to confirm the password in React.js. When I tried to implement and test it, I got a "Password does not match" even though I typed in the correct password. I am not sure what went wrong. Here is the code that I am working on with the password confirmation feature:

```
function validateSignupForm(payload) {
  const errors = {};
  let isFormValid = true;
  let message = '';

  if (!payload || typeof payload.email !== 'string' || !validator.isEmail(payload.email)) {
    isFormValid = false;
    errors.email = 'Please provide a correct email address.';
  }

  if (!payload || typeof payload.password !== 'string' || payload.password.trim().length < 8) {
    isFormValid = false;
    errors.password = 'Password must have at least 8 characters.';
  }

  //Trying to confirm password
  if (!payload || payload.password !== payload.password2) {
    isFormValid = false;
    errors.password2 = 'Password does not match.';
  }

  if (!payload || typeof payload.name !== 'string' || payload.name.trim().length === 0) {
    isFormValid = false;
    errors.name = 'Please provide your name.';
  }

  if (!isFormValid) {
    message = 'Check the form for errors.';
  }

  return {
    success: isFormValid,
    message,
    errors
  };
}
```

I attempted to add another `if` statement to see if that will work, but it did not and not sure what to do. Also, if it is not too much trouble, I would like to hash that confirmed password too.

Comment: have you checked payload.password2 actually returns something?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to console.log payload.password2 and nothing came out. However, I did get this message: `TextField is changing an uncontrolled input of type password2 to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).` I am not completely sure what that means. I have my repo [here](https://github.com/evo777/backlog-game) if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: Nevermind. I solved it. It was an issue with type property in the TextField. I can do the password confirm. However, there is still some issues that I need to figure out.